# Can't connect to Exchange server with Thunderbird or K-9

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, exchange

I would like to connect to an Exchange server without Outlook but my configuration seems to be wrong.

I was only able to connect to the server with BlueMail on my phone but I removed the app because it's sending data to BlueMail's servers. I would like to use Thunderbird and K-9 Mail.

I use **name@domain.com** as an example for the configuration. BlueMail used following incoming server settings (I couldn't access the outcoming server settings):
**Username:** \name
**Exchange server:** mail2.domain.com
**Security:** SSL/TLS (check certificate)
**Port:** 443

Both K-9 and Thunderbird are unable to connect with those details. Is it even possible to connect with those clients to an Exchange server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchange uses a proprietary protocol, which may be built into your phone.
Thunderbird doesn't have this proprietary protocol.

Thunderbird can sync email with Exchange through IMAP,
assuming IMAP is enabled on the server, but you need an add-on for that.

You might try
[ExQuilla for Microsoft Exchange](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/exquilla-exchange-web-services/):

> ExQuilla provides access to message reading and contacts in Thunderbird for users of Microsoft Exchange Server version 2007 and later.
>
> Previously this required a paid license. Versions 52 and earlier still require a license, but beginning in March 2018, those licenses are distributed automatically without charge. Upcoming version 60 will not require a license.

You could also try the
[DavMail Gateway](http://davmail.sourceforge.net/):

> DavMail is a POP/IMAP/SMTP/Caldav/Carddav/LDAP exchange gateway allowing users to use any mail/calendar client (e.g. Thunderbird with Lightning or Apple iCal) with an Exchange server, even from the internet or behind a firewall through Outlook Web Access. DavMail now includes an LDAP gateway to Exchange global address book and user personal contacts to allow recipient address completion in mail compose window and full calendar support with attendees free/busy display.

Comment: I wasn't able to use ExQuilla because I probably don't have an account on autodiscover.domain.com. I also wasn't able to enter the URL manually because it would still try to log into autodiscover.domain.com and not the one I entered.   
I then tried DavMail and I love it. I just had to adjust some ports and now it works. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Mozilla add-ons have the regrettable tendency of becoming non-functional when time passes. I'm glad DavMail worked for you.